# how to display the column names as default search textbox text in mvcjqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvcjqgrid

means if i am having a column  companyname, in search text i need to display text like company name

```
@(Html.Grid("CustomerInformation")
        .SetJsonReader(new MvcJqGrid.DataReaders.JsonReader { Id = "CustomerId", RepeatItems = false })
        .AddColumn(new Column("Code").SetKey(true).SetEditable(false).SetSearch(true))
        .AddColumn(new Column("Company Name").SetAlign(MvcJqGrid.Enums.Align.Cent![enter image description here][1]er).SetSearch(true).SetSortable(false).SetWidth(65).SetEditable(false))
        .AddColumn(new Column("E-Mail").SetAlign(MvcJqGrid.Enums.Align.Center).SetEditable(false).SetSearch(true))
```

there i add one java script for displaying columns names in search boxes
bt its giving same column name for all boxes

Comment: It's not clear to me what your asking. Could you be more specific, have a concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to set a default search value: http://mvcjqgrid.skaele.it/Home/DefaultSearchValue

Something like this:

```
.AddColumn(new Column("Name")
    .SetSearchType(Searchtype.Text)
    .SetDefaultSearchValue("Orland"))
```